# How can I fix lagging sound in when playing videos?

Tags: windows-7, audio, lag

Sometimes, when I am playing a video, the sound lags the video by a bit (±2 seconds is not unheard of). Is there a player that can go two seconds ahead on the audio, or two second behind? It would need to be able to play .avi and .flv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has the option to change the audio delay. While there isn't a menu shortcut for this (I didn't even find anything related to "synchronization"), you can do it with the keyboard:

- <kbd>f</kbd> decreases the audio delay
- <kbd>g</kbd> increases the audio delay

The shortcuts can be changed in the Hotkeys section of VLC's preferences (should be the same for Windows, can't test right now).

[image]

While this masks the effects of lagging audio, it of course depends on the cause of the lag if that's a solution you can live with. If the video stream itself is delayed, you could re-wrap it in another container and fix the delay.

Answer (score -1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can do it, and is the best media player out there.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this in VLC?

Comment: Echoing above comment. How?

Comment: its under "synchronization"